# Multible objects creation in Django Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My desire is to create several objects in one django admin-panel creation window. Look:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model)
   field1 = models.CharField()
   field2 = models.CharField()
   field3 = models.CharField()
   date = models.DateField()
```

In this case most important part is date, Often I create objects in admin-panel, where first 3 field are the same(at the moment of creation) and only date must be unique. So I wanna integrate some widget where I can choose all dates that i need, and by clicking submit button create number of objects.

I found package named **django-bulk-admin**, which can solve my task. But it is not supported in Django 3. Also ChatGPT suggested me to create some actions in Admin class definition, but it is not works. I guess solution is redefine action of AdminForm of this model, but I don't know how?

**UPDATE.** This is actual model that i designing at the moment(simplified version).  Administrator adds lessons using admin-panel. Imagine some group #1, in 1 semester(semester=60 days) will have lessons three days per week. Approximately we will have about 25 lessons. **Each lesson must be seperate object.** These 25 lessons as objects will be almost equal, only dates will be unique. So that's why I'm trying to add many objects in one time, choosing multiple dates. These objects(lessons) in future will have unique information about status of lesson and other additional information, but at the moment of creation they're differ only by date.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    study_group = models.ForeignKey(StudyGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.CharField(choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES)
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(default='the lesson was not held')
    reason_for_not_held = models.TextField(default = 'lesson not started yet..') #if status is 'the lesson wasn't held'
    substitute_teacher = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #if status is 'the lesson has been transferred to another teacher'
```

Comment: And I know maybe logically easier not to use admin-panel for this task , but I wanna do this in admin-panel :)

Comment: Actually if rows have (often) the same value, this is a (strong) sign that the modeling is wrong. lilely you want to use a model `Foo` with `field1`, `field2` and `field3`, and then another model `FooDate` for example with a `ForeignKey` to `Foo` and with a `DateField`.

Comment: You're right. So can you look at my actual model, i'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

If the same value occurs often in the same column(s), and that is not a coincidence like two people that "happen" to have the same name, this is called *data duplication*, and data duplication often is a bad thing: it makes the database larger, but also the data less easy to manage: if for example you entered the wrong `substitute_teacher`, that would mean you need to update all lessons for that sequence.

Usually the solution is to create two models, where the second model contains data specific *per instance* and a `ForeignKey` to the first item that contains the data that is common. Here that would mean something like:

```
class LessonSequence(models.Model):
    study_group = models.ForeignKey(StudyGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.CharField(choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES)
    substitute_teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )


class Lesson(models.Model):
    lesson_sequence = models.ForeignKey(LessonSequence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(default='the lesson was not held')
    reason_for_not_held = models.TextField(
        default='lesson not started yet..'
    )  # if status is 'the lesson wasn't held'
```

Often you want then see or edit the related items in the `ModelAdmin` in bulk, and the Django admin has something for this: [**`inlines`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines). Indeed, you can work with a `ModelAdmin` for the `LessonSequence` (and you can if you want make one for the `Lesson` model), additionally we can create an [**`TabularInline`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline), or [**`StackedInline`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline) for `Lesson`s in the `ModelAdmin` for `LessonSequence`:

```
# app_name/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin


class LessonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Lesson


@admin.register(LessonSequence)
class LessonSequenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        LessonInline,
    ]
    # …
```

Comment: Dislike, you didn't understand the problem at all

Comment: (a) did you implement this, and (b) what is not answering your expectations then?

Comment: just read my question once again, the main task is change the page (form) for creating a Lesson model object, so that several instances of the Lesson model are created at a time, with one click of the 'submit' button. To do this, in the form of the admin panel, I would like to have some special widget in which you can select N number of dates and not one. And thus, N Lesson model objects are created, with the same (initially) values except for the date.

Comment: @Nurtugang: well that is what the inline does :) It translates to a formset with an arbitrary number of items, this will look like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52621063/67579 but the modeling is simply wrong: it violates first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: oh really??? hmmm, sorry and thank you!